# Can someone explain this JS code and error to me? Why does it fail?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to access a public-facing site (not one that I developed but is being used as a reference site) and it does not load in IE8 (which is our corporate standard browser).  It loads fine in Chrome (not all users have it).  The error I receive is "res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm...".  Do I have to configure IE8 in some way to render this?  Any and all assistance to better troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

I looked at the source via "View source" and I see the following towards the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/jquery.scroll.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
          $.extend(  $.mobile , {
            ajaxFormsEnabled : false,
                ajaxLinksEnabled : false
          });
        });
        </script> 


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
```

Does the above code snippet suffice to assist with some advice or is the whole HTML document needed?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about the IE8 browser and not about code - you indicate you are not the developer and cannot change the code.  This question probably belongs on SuperUser.com, not here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to start by wrapping that in a

```
$(document).ready(function{

});
```

segment, otherwise you may run into all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Indeed, the 'mobileinit' code is being executed while the jquery mobile library hasn't loaded yet. It's best to wait for the dom ready event.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I have edited my post by noting that I am not a developer of the site and thus do not have access to the code.

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a problem, as that is an obvious bug that can make any number of other things not work correctly... and it is likely the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately your question is too vague to get you a reliable answer, however a quick google search landed me on this:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/resieframedll-error-in-ie-8/7f657540-474f-4587-b661-c3ffbb1aed06

So I am suspecting it's a problem with your installation of ie8. If not please supply more info :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have edited my post with further information.  Before posting on SO, I have tried searching for this error and have noticed that same link before, but it doesn't help I feel.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt jQuery Mobile has much support for IE8. It's built with mobile browsers in mind so the main rendering engines would be Webkit(Chrome) and Gecko(Fx). It's that simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have updated my post with further information.  Your answer is inline with my thinking and I believe it is the answer.

Comment: JQuery Mobile is supported by IE 8 (as long as its the correct version of course) There may be some small css issues, but functionality should be all there [source](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)

Comment: Indeed, what's the bet that the corporate version is heavily stripped down.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery mobile is [supported by IE 8](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) if it is the correct version, but this line here may be the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
          $.extend(  $.mobile , {
            ajaxFormsEnabled : false,
                ajaxLinksEnabled : false
          });
        });
        </script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
```

You are calling something with mobile before your mobile script is imported. You need to first import your mobile script, then do a `document.ready()` call a Javascript function at the VERY END of you html page that will run all init functions.

[This](https://gist.github.com/723870) is one of the few calls you want to run before loading JQuery Mobile

```
//run this script after jQuery loads, but before jQuery Mobile loads, and may help solve your issue

//customize jQuery Mobile to let IE7+ in (Mobile IE)
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend( $.mobile , {

  //extend gradeA qualifier to include IE7+
    gradeA: function(){
     //IE version check by James Padolsey, modified by jdalton - from http://gist.github.com/527683
var ie = (function() {
var v = 3, div = document.createElement('div'), a = div.all || [];
while (div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><br><![endif]-->', a[0]);
return v > 4 ? v : !v;
}());

     //must either support media queries or be IE7+
     return $.support.mediaquery || (ie && ie >= 7);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: An anonymous edit to this answer suggests the following: 
--------------
This is incorrect. jQuery Mobile documantation clearly states mobileint should be called before the library is loaded. cdf : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html
------

Comment: Hmmm. That may be the case now. I haven't used JQuery Mobile for around 2 - 3 years so a lot may have changed.